# For a function that updates a world "state", I want to return a vector of strings of events that happened

Tags: clojure

I have this small game world state, something like the following:

```
(defn odds [percentage]
  (< (rand-int 100) percentage))

(defn world []
  {:entities []})

(defn make-bird []
  {:pos [(rand-int 100) (rand-int 100)]
   :age 0
   :dir (vec/dir (rand (. Math PI)))})

(defn generate-entities [entities]
  (if (odds 10)
    (conj entities (make-bird))
    entities))

(defn update-entity [entity]
  (-> entity
      (update :pos (partial vec/add (:dir entity)))
      (update :age inc)))

(defn update-entities [entities]
  (vec (map update-entity entities)))

(defn old? [{age :age}]
  (> age 10))

(defn prune-entities [entities]
  (vec (filter #(not (old? %)) entities)))

(defn update-world [world]
  (-> world
      (update :entities generate-entities)
      (update :entities update-entities)
      (update :entities prune-entities)))
```

So `update-world` goes through three steps. First there's a 1/10 chance of generating a new bird entity, which flies in a random direction. Then it updates all birds, updating their position and incrementing their `age`. Then it prunes all old birds.
I use this same technique for generating particles systems. You can do fun stuff like `(iterate update-world (world))` to get a lazy list of world states which you can consume at whatever frame rate you want.

However, I now have a game world with autonomous entities which roam around and do stuff, kind of like the birds. But I want to get a textual representation of what happened when evaluating `update-world`. For example, `update-world` would ideally return a tuple of the new world state and a vector of strings - `["A bird was born at [12, 8].", "A bird died of old age at [1, 2]."]`.

But then I really can't use `(iterate update-world (world))` anymore. I can't really see how to do this.
Is this something you'd use `with-out-string` for?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enhance only your top-level function (`update-world`) in your case you can just create a wrapper function that you can use in `iterate`. A simple example:

```
(defn increment [n]
  (inc n))

(defn logging-increment [[_ n]]
  (let [new-n (increment n)]
    [(format "Old: %s New: %s" n new-n) new-n]))

(take 3 (iterate logging-increment [nil 0]))
;; => ([nil 0] ["Old: 0 New: 1" 1] ["Old: 1 New: 2" 2])
```

In case you want to do it while collecting data at multiple level and you don't want to modify the signatures of your existing functions (e.g. you want to use it only for debugging), then using dynamic scope seems like a reasonable option.

Alternatively you can consider using some tracing tools, like [`clojure/tools.trace`](https://github.com/clojure/tools.trace#example-usage). You could turn on and off logging of your function calls by simply changing `defn` to `deftrace` or using `trace-ns` or `trace-vars`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two potential issues with using `with-out-str`

- It returns a string, not a vector.  If you *need* to use a vector, you'll need to use something else.
- Only the string is returned.  If you are using `with-out-str` to wrap a side-effect (e.g., `swap!`), this might be fine.

For debugging purposes, I usually just use `println`.  You can use `with-out` if you want control over where the output goes.  You could even implement a custom stream that collects the output into a vector of strings if you wanted.  You could get similar results with a dynamically bound vector that you accumulate (via `set!`) the output string (or wrap the vector in an atom and use `swap!`).

If the accumulated vector is part of the computation per se, and you want to remain pure, you might consider using a [monad](https://github.com/clojure/algo.monads).

Answer (score 1):

What about using `clojure.data/diff` to generate the string representation of changes? You could do something like this:

```
(defn update-world [[world mutations]]
  (let [new-world (-> world
                      (update :entities generate-entities)
                      (update :entities update-entities)
                      (update :entities prune-entities))]
    [new-world (mutations (clojure.data/diff world new-world))]))
```

Then you could do something like `(iterate update-world [(world) []])` to get the ball rolling.